# Did Houdini make any creative contribution to Under the Pyramids?

Tags: h-p-lovecraft

It is well know that H. P. Lovecraft wrote the story "[Under the Pyramids](http://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/up.aspx)" (also known as "Imprisoned with the Pharaohs") for the world-famous magician and escape artist Harry Houdini.  Houdini narrates the story, and it was published under the magician's name.  What I am wondering is simple:  Was the story wholly a creation of Lovecraft, or did Houdini also make some creative contribution to it?

Answer (score 2):

The starting point was an anecdote of Houdini's which he claimed to be true. Lovecraft did some research and realised that it couldn't be and then asked his editor if he could have free reign to write the story as he pleased.
I don't know (though I would like to, which is how I got here) how much of Houdini's original story is in the final one but it seems fair to assume at least some of it is, if only the setting and the being chained up and left under the pyramids. Though that is just guess work on my part.

Comment: Do you have any evidence you can [edit] in for the first sentence? You seem to be claiming fact so it would be nice to see where this has come from.